# SDL_GetMouseState doesn't work to get initial mouse position

Tags: sdl, mouse-coordinates, sdl-2

Is there a way to get initial position of mouse in *SDL 2.0* ?  
 I try to get mouse coordinates by `SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_x,&mouse_y)`, however I get the result I expected only after using the function `SDL_PollEvent()` and also I can't see a value other than `(0,0)` if the mouse has not been moved at least once since begining of the program.Although I don't check **SDL_MOUSEMOTION** and connect `SDL_GetMouseState()` to it, I get mouse coordinates only when mouse is moved.So what's wrong? Or is `SDL_GetMouseState()` suitable to do so?
Edit : Why, Why is there no any answer?

Comment: Which OS are you using SDL2 on?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling SDL_PumpEvents() before SDL_GetMouseState().

Comment: I already tried it but I didn't get the result I expect.I have just tried it again, no change.

Comment: @user2561614: So you're doing something like `SDL_Init(); SDL_CreateWindow(); SDL_PumpEvents(); SDL_GetMouseState()`?  Because on my Win7 system that gives me a reasonable (non-zero) x/y if my mouse is initially inside the window.

Comment: Reproduced same result with zeros for x and y on Kubuntu 18.04. This happens when cursor is out of SDL window on start.

Answer (score 2):

The SDL updates the position of the mouse internally in [SDL_PrivateSendMouseMotion](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/54c06b0f65d9/src/events/SDL_mouse.c#l191), which is called by various mouse related functions in the same file.

These functions are called in the event loop processing function [WIN_WindowProc](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/54c06b0f65d9/src/video/windows/SDL_windowsevents.c#l287) in response to the mouse events dispatched by Windows.

Thus, if you do not move the mouse, no event is dispatched and the SDL does not know where the mouse is. The solution is to wait for a mouse event before requesting the position and to find a workaround until this event.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but just chipping in with a resolution I found.
If you get zero coordinates, call SDL_GetGlobalMouseState(&x, &y) then offset x and y by the window.x and window.y coordinates.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as expected, the Y coordinate counts the title bar's height, and I found no way of getting this value to substract it